# C#: How do I extract href and src data from HTML

Tags: c#, html

I have a HTML file that has many lines like the following:

```
<a href="/n/lastname" class="profimg">
    <img src="http://images.nosite.com/profiles/profile_183140203_75sq_1393790252.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
</a>
```

I need to extract both the href and src tag information.  I downloaded the htmlagilitypack and it seems to simplify the process but right now I can either get one or the other.  How can I get both?  Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to get both of the values so that we can show you what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

How about this, you can use jquery [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to reference the `img` available within your `<a>` tag

```
var href = $(".profimg").attr('href');
var src = $(".profimg > img").attr("src");

alert(href); // /n/lastname
alert(src); // http://images.nosite.com/profiles/profile_183140203_75sq_1393790252.jpg
```

Comment: jQuery is far from being C# :-)